# How to get value from input text with ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="regular" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cari</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="cari" name="cari" required>
            <option>Silahkan Pilih</option>
            <?php foreach($cari_komponen as $row){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['id_komponen'] ?>"><?php echo $row['kdgiat'] ?> - <?php echo $row['kdoutput'] ?> - <?php echo $row['kdkmpnen'] ?> - <?php echo $row['urkmpnen'] ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <div class="form-control-line"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="regular" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Kode Kegiatan</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kode_kegiatan" name="kode_kegiatan" required="required" disabled><div class="form-control-line"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="regular" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Kode Output</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kode_output" name="kode_output" required="required" disabled><div class="form-control-line"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="regular" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Kode Sub Output</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kode_sub_output" name="kode_sub_output" required="required" disabled><div class="form-control-line"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="regular" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Kode Komponen</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kode_komponen" name="kode_komponen" required="required"><div class="form-control-line"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="regular" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Uraian Komponen</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uraian_komponen" name="uraian_komponen" required="required" disabled><div class="form-control-line"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="regular" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Kode Sub Kompenen</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kode_sub_komponen" name="kode_sub_komponen" required="required" disabled><div class="form-control-line"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="regular" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Uraian Sub Komponen</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uraian_sub_komponen" name="uraian_sub_komponen" required="required" disabled><div class="form-control-line"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ajax post:

```
$('#cari').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url     : '<?php echo base_url() ?>rekam/realisasi_anggaran/get_komponen',
        type    : 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data    : { cari: $('#cari').val() },
        success: function( data ) {
            if(!data['result']){
            }else{
                $('#kode_kegiatan').val(data['kode_kegiatan']);
                $('#kode_output').val(data['kode_output']);
                $('#kode_sub_output').val(data['kode_sub_output']);
                $('#kode_komponen').val(data['kode_komponen']);
                $('#uraian_komponen').val(data['uraian_komponen']);
                $('#kode_sub_komponen').val(data['kode_sub_komponen']);
                $('#uraian_sub_komponen').val(data['uraian_sub_komponen']);
            }
        }
    });
});

$('#kode_komponen').live(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url     : '<?php echo base_url() ?>rekam/realisasi_anggaran/get_komponens',
        type    : 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data    : { cari: $('#cari').val() },
        success: function( data ) {
            if(!data['result']){
            }else{
                $('#kode_kegiatan').val(data['kode_kegiatan']);
                $('#kode_output').val(data['kode_output']);
                $('#kode_sub_output').val(data['kode_sub_output']);
                $('#kode_komponen').val(data['kode_komponen']);
                $('#uraian_komponen').val(data['uraian_komponen']);
                $('#kode_sub_komponen').val(data['kode_sub_komponen']);
                $('#uraian_sub_komponen').val(data['uraian_sub_komponen']);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I want to get live value that generated from my first ajax post (#kode_komponen) and pass it to another ajax post.
Is that possible? Because i tried using .live or .change on #kode_komponen but it doesnt work.

Comment: Yes. Store the value returned from the first AJAX call, perhaps in a hidden field used during the second AJAX call.

Comment: live was removed from jquery 1.9 and is just an event handler (clickes, changes, etc).

Comment: so tell us, what is the version of jQuery you're using here? it might be the reason why your code is failing, that's "if" it's failing because of it.

Comment: and make sure `foreach($cari_komponen as $row` isn't failing you. check for errors, check your console.

Comment: I'm using jquery.1.11 version. still don't know what to do ;(

Comment: Change from `.live()` to [`.on()`] for that version of jQuery as @Aman points out in his answer.

Comment: still doesnt work jay. What i want to do is get the value from input field that generated from $('#cari')

Comment: so there we have it, it's your version of jQuery and the function you're using being deprecated/deleted.

Comment: Did you put the value you got from the first AJAX call into an element that you can retrieve from the second AJAX call?

Comment: and make sure that this isn't failing you `foreach($cari_komponen as $row)...` as I already said. Check for errors like I said earlier http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and if using a DB for this, check for errors on the query. Your question being unresolved after all this time, is unclear. Nothing else for me to do to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

[`Live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is just an event handler to listen to an event. In your example you have called `live` which should actually be replaced by  [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Basically, you should have your code like this

```
$('#kode_komponen').on('click', function() {
//code here
});
```

You need to attach an event e.g. `click` to the handler `on`

Comment: Depends on the version of jQuery the OP is using.

Comment: it doesnt work, my 2nd ajax working when i clicked the input field, not get live value from 1st ajax post